# учим рекурсию в универе) Существует монотонная последовательность 1 2 2 3 3 3...и так далее

Tags: c, рекурсия, числовые-последовательности

нужно по заданному пользователем N вывести N членов этой последовательности.

на данный момент реализована сумма такой последовательности. но увы, не знаю, как вывести элементы должным образом.

сперва была идея в сумму записывать каждый раз +1, потом делать вложенный цикл, который бы мог по числу определить, сколько раз надо вводить данный элемент (то есть, например, есть 2, соответственно, мне требуется 2 раза ввести данное число в строку) и выводить его. также такому подходу нужно ограничение, чтобы не выйти за допустимое число, введенное пользователем.

не могу сложить в голове последовательность реализации, хочется все-таки разобраться

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int reccur(int d)
{
int sum = 0;
int j = 0;
if (d == 1)
    return (1);
else
    for (int i = 1; sum < d; i++)
    {
        sum += i;
        j = i;
    }
return (reccur(--d) + j);

 }

void main() 
{
int n;
printf("enter the number ");
scanf_s("%d", &n);
printf("\n%d",reccur(n));
puts("\nrecursion has been done\n");
}
```

Comment: N - это последнее число или количество? Ну, для N=5 что выводить - 1 2 2 3 3 или 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5?

Comment: N-количество выведенных цифр)

Comment: Надеюсь, что таки чисел) С цифрами ещё сложнее)

Comment: то есть пользователь вводит, допустим, 6 и в поле вывода должен получить:  1 2 2 3 3 4, у меня уже сломався мозг

Comment: Стоп-стоп, почему 4? 1 2 2 3 3 3 - одна единица, две двойки, три тройки, нет?

Comment: случился миссклик. да, вы правы

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<stdio.h>

void reccur_c(int max_num, int num) {
    int already_printed = (num-1)*num / 2;
    for (int i = 0; i < num && already_printed + i < max_num; i++){
        printf("%d ", num);
    }

    if (already_printed + num < max_num){
        reccur_c(max_num, num + 1);
    }
}
void reccur(int n) {
    reccur_c(n, 1);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    reccur(11);
}
```

> ```
> 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5
> ```

Comment: а зачем появляется теперь 2 функции, одна из которых (reccur_c) вроде как мне понятна-в ней выполняются все действия с переменными; а вот зачем вот эта:                      
    void reccur(int n)                                                                                                                             
 {
    reccur_c(n, 1);
 }

Comment: и можно ли в main скопировать ввод n пользователем, как это было у меня?

Comment: Думаю, с этим вы справитесь

Comment: Вторая функция появляется для учёта текущей итерации, чтобы не менять интерфейс вызываемой функции

Answer (score 1):

Другое решение, с решением квадратного уравнения для поиска индекса треугольного числа))

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void solution(int n) {
    if (n == 0) return;
    solution(n - 1);
    int i = ceil((1+sqrt(1+8*n))/2) - 1; // Ищем индекс треугольного числа
    printf("%d ", i);
}
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    solution(57);
    printf("\n");
}
```

> ```
> 1 2 2 3 3 3 4 4 4 4 5 5 5 5 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 7 7 7 7 7 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 8 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 9 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 10 11 11
> ```